# Compiling PHP 5 with PDO MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, configuration, pdo

I want to use Nginx with PHP5-FPM with MySQL PDO on Debian. To get PHP5-FPM on squeeze I need to compile PHP myself. First I tried to

I did:

```
apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
```

I downloaded PHP 5.3.6. Then I configured PHP like this:

```
./configure \
--enable-fpm \
--enable-soap \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-libxml \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-zend-multibyte \
--enable-zip \
--with-openssl \
--with-zlib \
--with-mcrypt \
--enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql \
--with-gd
```

The make process quits with this error:

> /php-5.3.6/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c:76:
>   error: "pdo_mysql_stmt" has no member
>   named "in_length"

What am I doing wrong? Should I use package `libmysqlclient-dev`? I want maximum performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use

```
--enable-pdo --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

PHP compiles.